# Looping 'find...-type f': Getting filenames by dir/subdir, ouputing a txt with name dir_subdir_fname.txt

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, perl

My data structure is something like:

```
dir1/subdir1_level1/subdir1_level2.../subdir1_leveln
dir1/subdir2_level1/subdir2_level2.../subdir2_leveln
...
```

Which means that the levels I'm working with are not structured properly, nevertheless.
I managed to accomplish my objective of getting the filename according to the first 2 levels of the path, and output them to a text file named dirn_subdirn_fname.txt with:

```
find dir1/subdir1 -type f -printf "%f\n">dir1_subdir1_fname.txt
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to Iterate this process across a list of several dir/subdir's

edit: I found a way to do the first part:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob nullglob

topdir= './Dir1'

 for subdir in "$topdir"; do
    find "$subdir" -type f -printf "%f\n"
done
```

Comment: Probably something like `for pathname in dir1/*/ ; do find "$pathname" -type f  > "$pathname"_fname.txt; done` ?  Or `find dir1/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" > "$(basename "$1" )"_fname.txt' sh {} \;` ?

Comment: Can you [edit] to add a sample of the output you'd like? As in what output you want to what files? I think you want the contents of `dir1/foo/` to `dir1_foo.txt`, and the contents of `dir1/bar/` to `dir1_bar.txt`, etc. but I'm not sure?

Comment: @ilkkachu you are correct in that assumption. The output is what `-printf "%f\n"` shows, just a list of the filenames (with extension) stored in dir/subdir.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly try with below script

it will print up to 9 subdirectories  files using find command keyword maxdepth


    for i in {1..9}; do echo "below are files under $i steep afer parent path subdirectory"; find . -maxdepth $i -type f;echo "================================"; done
```